# How do I implement these 2 waypoints - infinite live scroll, and sticky header?

Tags: javascript, html, sticky-footer, sticky

I am using 2 waypoints to implement

```
1. a sticky header (http://imakewebthings.com/jquery-waypoints/sticky-elements/)
2. An infinite live scroll (http://imakewebthings.com/jquery-waypoints/infinite-scroll/)
```

The  header works.  But as soon as the live scroll is triggered, the sticky header goes back to it's original position and "Top" button at the bottom also vanishes. Live scroll continues to work though.

I tried calling the stickyHeader function again when the live scroll starts. But that does not help.
My stickyHeader function is as follows,

```
var stickyHeader = function() {

  $('.top').addClass('hidden');
  $('body').waypoint(function(event, direction) {
      $('.top').toggleClass('hidden', direction === "up");
  }, {
      offset: '-100%'
  }).find('#stickyHeaderText').waypoint(function(event, direction) {
      $(this).parent().toggleClass('sticky', direction === "down");
      event.stopPropagation();
  });

};
```

**Update:**
    Infinite scroll

```
        var opts = {
            offset: '100%'
        };

        var $footer = $('#footerDivId');
        $footer.waypoint(function(event, direction) {
            $footer.waypoint('remove');
            ftr.remove();
                    // get more data
            $footer.waypoint(opts);
        }, opts);

        stickyHeader();
```

Comment: Titles should describe, in a summary, what you're asking